# uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in my javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/pagedown/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/pagedown/Showdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
        var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
        editor.run();
    });
</script>
```

But when I run this I am getting a message saying:

```
uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: Is the jQuery library referenced from your page?

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` Add this before your script tag.

Comment: your `<script>` tags clearly tell that you forgot to include jQuery library

Comment: Maybe the example I used was not correct. I am using https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/  It seems not to need jQuery. However the user giving some instructions gave the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is not using jQuery.

Just do this:

```
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
```

Put that in your script.  [Got the idea from here](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js)

To be honest, I would use

```
var $ = function (id) { return (document.getElementById(id)) ? document.getElementById(id) : document.getElementsByClassName(id); };
```

Answer (score 0):

$ is not defined because your script/library is not loaded yet.
Try Load your script in the  section.

Comment: I just updated my question. The script is loaded before this but it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/pagedown/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/pagedown/Showdown.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script><!--jquery script added here-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
        var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
        editor.run();
    });
</script>
```

Try this